# Remove searchView icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In my app, I'm using a SearchView in the actionbar that it's always expanded like this:

[image]

My main.xml is this:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Search" />
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItem searchViewItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchViewItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    return true;
}
```

**I would like to remove the search icon and expand the editText.**

Regards